# Why IP is not pointing to Joomla main page

Tags: url, web, joomla

Given the following URL: `htttp://domain/index.php`, where `index.php` is the main webpage in a joomla server. I want to get the URL with the IP format, `http://IP/index.php`. I've tried that with several Joomla servers without success. What is it happening?

Comment: are you on a shared IP? Like shared webhosting?

Comment: yes, probably... how does it work exactly?

Comment: In shared hosting multiple clients are on the same IP, so when a domain is passed in, the DNS is mapped to the shared IP, and the router on the server assigns a virtual IP based on the domain. So going with just an IP the server wouldn't know which domain you are accessing. There may be a way by accessing path, but I don't know for sure

Comment: Why are you trying to access it by IP Address? Is the domain not pointing at the hosting yet? Depending on the host, there is usually a way to access the site without the domain routed correctly, but it would help to know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to keep this answer simple, yet understandable.

The relation between Internet domains and IP address is not necessarily one-to-one.

In shared hosting, a single IP address may be used by several domains (or hostnames).

A `Host` header, which is a part of the HTTP standard, is sent with the HTTP request. This allows the server to determine which site to serve.

When you are trying to access a domain for which you don't know the IP, DNS lookup is performed, which provides the requested IP address.

A HTTP request is then sent to that IP with a `Host` header with the hostname (which contains the domain name).

If you are trying to access the ip directly, for example by typing in a web browser's address bar, the value of the `Host` header will be the IP itself and the server will have no indication what domain you actually want.

It is possible to set up a default behavior for cases where the IP address is directly accessed, but it is highly likely that a shared host will not allow you to set it yourself.